# how to place csv file on local sharepoint and store & retrive date of csv with HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, csv, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created data entry simple HTML form (data could be text and numbers only) and I have used csv file as backend database for storing HTML fom values directly into csv file using javascript.

Now I want to publish this HTML form on local microsoft sharepoint and also I want to keep this csv database file on sharepoint.

How to do checkin and checkout using javascript and how to publish HTML page and csv file on local sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just publish these things to SharePoint and expect them to work. One thing you might be able to get away with is using something like the content editor web part to do your html and JavaScript in. However, you're going to run into access issues with your 'back-end database file.' SharePoint isn't going to like that.

I would suggest doing this the proper way. Create an empty SharePoint project within Visual Studio so it's a proper SharePoint page and using the SharePoint object model. If you do it this way, you can basically do a one-click publish to SharePoint.